# Mounting NTFS partition problem

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

My external HDD suddenly turned corrupt after reboot. It is connected on USB port. I couldn't mount it. I tried the ntfsfix command and got this result

`$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdg Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing. FAILED Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing. FAILED Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument NTFS signature is missing. Trying the alternate boot sector Unrecoverable error Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.`

So I tried chkdsk /f on Windows as instructed which showed no error at all. In Windows 10 it works perfectly.

Then I switched back to Linux and used testdisk to repair MFT, it says MFT matches perfectly and didnt fix it.

Is there any way to fix this without formatting it on Linux system? Im using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Linux NTFS driver will not mount hibernated NTFS. And Windows fast start up sets hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions. Windows also turns fast start up back on with updates. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Ok gonna try it. Out of curiosity, I have several NTFS partitions connected and only 2 have the problem. If it flags all, why other partitions arent affected.

Comment: Turns out that the drives are not hibernated